# Play mov files in PyQt

Tags: video, pyqt, pyqt4, quicktime, phonon

I'd like to open a mov file in my PyQt application with a Quicktime-like  player.

I am trying to use the phonon module but somehow I can't get it to work.

In my ui file (generated by Qt designer) it is initialized like this :

```
self.videoPlayer = phonon.Phonon.VideoPlayer(self.gridLayoutWidget)
self.videoPlayer.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("videoPlayer"))
```

And in my code I try this :

```
media_source = phonon.Phonon.MediaSource("path\\to\\my\\media.mov")
self.ui.videoPlayer.load(media_source)
self.ui.videoPlayer.play()
```

Can someone point me out where I'm doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code you posted. If your system has the necessary codecs available, there's no reason why phonon shouldn't be able to play quicktime files.

Below is a simple phonon demo that plays quicktime files for me (on Linux, using the GStreamer backend). The demo also lists all the available mime-types that the current phonon backend can handle. On my system, the mime-type "video/quicktime" is shown in the list.

If you run it in a console, it will also print out any phonon error messages.

**EDIT**

It appears that, on windows, phonon may use Windows Media Player as the backend. If so, then it may be necessary to install some extra codecs for WMP so that it can play quicktime files.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.phonon import Phonon

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.media = Phonon.MediaObject(self)
        self.media.stateChanged.connect(self.handleStateChanged)
        self.video = Phonon.VideoWidget(self)
        self.video.setMinimumSize(400, 400)
        self.audio = Phonon.AudioOutput(Phonon.VideoCategory, self)
        Phonon.createPath(self.media, self.audio)
        Phonon.createPath(self.media, self.video)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Choose File', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        self.list = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        self.list.addItems(Phonon.BackendCapabilities.availableMimeTypes())
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.video, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.list)

    def handleButton(self):
        if self.media.state() == Phonon.PlayingState:
            self.media.stop()
        else:
            path = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, self.button.text())
            if path:
                self.media.setCurrentSource(Phonon.MediaSource(path))
                self.media.play()

    def handleStateChanged(self, newstate, oldstate):
        if newstate == Phonon.PlayingState:
            self.button.setText('Stop')
        elif (newstate != Phonon.LoadingState and
              newstate != Phonon.BufferingState):
            self.button.setText('Choose File')
            if newstate == Phonon.ErrorState:
                source = self.media.currentSource().fileName()
                print ('ERROR: could not play:', source.toLocal8Bit().data())
                print ('  %s' % self.media.errorString().toLocal8Bit().data())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('Phonon Player')
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I tried to run your demo. It says in the list that it supports quicktime files, but when I try to play a .mov file it says that the format is not supported ...

Comment: @Johanna. What's the _exact_ error message? Can you play the quicktime file with other applications? Also: what platform are you on, and what version of Qt are you using?

Comment: The exact error message is "ERROR : could not play <file>. Impossible to read the file. The format is not supported". I can read the files just fine with quicktime. And I'm using PyQT4 on Windows 7.

Comment: @Johanna. Those error messages are specific to Windows Media Player, which phonon is using as the backend on your system. So it could be that WMP is not configured to play quicktime files.

Comment: @Johanna. Update: I tried the demo on Windows XP, and found I could not play quicktime files until I installed some extra codecs for WMP. I've also edited the demo slightly, because, on windows, the video widget wasn't resizing itself properly (i.e. zero height).

Comment: I installed the K-Lite package and WMP can read mov files. But your app still can't. Still says that the format is not supported

Comment: Is it possible that it is not working because of the fact that I am using windows 64bits ?

Comment: @Johanna. I also installed K-LIte, but my Windows XP installation is 32-bit. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5928233/984421), it is certainly possible that your problem is caused by incompatible codecs.

Comment: I installed the 64 bits K-lite codecs and now I can read some of mov files but not all of them. I guess it depends on what codec was used to generate them. It says some streams in the file are not supported.